# COM object method undefined

Tags: php, windows, delphi, com

I'm having troubles calling any method inside a COM class in php. In order to find all methods inside that class, I used:

```
$com = new COM('Some.Class.Name');
com_print_typeinfo($com);
```

Comes out this class contains some 100 different methods. But when calling any of them:

```
$com->SomeMethod();
```

,this error pops up:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method com::SomeMethod() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\www\test.php on line 22

This doesn't happen when I use other COM objects, like '**InternetExplorer.Application**' class.
Also, I know this COM object works as expected with other programming languages like Delphi.

I'm using PHP 5.5.19, on 64-bit Windows Vista, and XAMPP, with 32-bit PHP architecture.

I would appreciate any lead on what may be going on or some possible workaround to this situation.

**EDIT:** 
**The COM server application is made with Delphi.**

This might be another clue: When I use the code

```
$com = new COM('Some.Class.Name');
foreach ($com as $obj) { 
    echo $obj->Name . "<br />"; 
}
```

I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Object of
>   type com did not create an Iterator'

I guess this indicates there could be a problem with the application interface itself, but I don't know what that problem might be. I work in PHP, so the insides of COM objects are a total blur to me. But I would very much appreciate any clue on the concrete steps in order to fix this situation.

**EDIT2:**
This is the ***in short*** code from the *Srv_TLB.pas* file.

```
unit Srv_TLB;

{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
{$WRITEABLECONST ON}
{$VARPROPSETTER ON}
interface

uses Windows, ActiveX, Classes, Graphics, StdVCL, Variants;

const
  // TypeLibrary Major and minor versions
  SrvMajorVersion = 1;
  SrvMinorVersion = 0;

  LIBID_Srv: TGUID = '{xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xx...}';

  IID_ISrvObject: TGUID = '{yyyyy-yyy-yyy-yy..}';
  CLASS_SrvObject: TGUID = '{zzzzz-zzz-zzz-z...}';
type

// *********************************************************************//
// Forward declaration of types defined in TypeLibrary                    
// *********************************************************************//
  ISrvObject = interface;
  ISrvObjectDisp = dispinterface;

// *********************************************************************//
// Declaration of CoClasses defined in Type Library                       
// (NOTE: Here we map each CoClass to its Default Interface)              
// *********************************************************************//
  SrvObject = ISrvObject;

  ISrvObject = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{yyyyy-yyy-yyy-yy..}']
    function FuncName1(const param1: WideString; const param2: WideString): Integer; safecall;
    function FuncName2: OleVariant; safecall;
    function FuncName3(const param: WideString): Integer; safecall;
  end;

    // *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf:  ISrvObjectDisp
// Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {yyyyy-yyy-yyy-yy..}
// *********************************************************************//
  ISrvObjectDisp = dispinterface
    ['{yyyyy-yyy-yyy-yy..}']
    function FuncName1(const param1: WideString; const param2: WideString): Integer; dispid 3;
    function FuncName2: OleVariant; dispid 4;
    function FuncName3(const param: WideString): Integer; dispid 5;
  end;

    CoSrvObject = class
    class function Create: ISrvObject;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): ISrvObject;
  end;

implementation

uses ComObj;

class function CoSrvObject.Create: ISrvObject;
begin
  Result := CreateComObject(CLASS_SrvObject) as ISrvObject;
end;

class function CoSrvObject.CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): ISrvObject;
begin
  Result := CreateRemoteComObject(MachineName, CLASS_SrvObject) as ISrvObject;
end;

end.
```

And the problem is (from the PHP side of things):
I can initialize the COM object with `$com = new COM('The.Class.Name');` or with `$com = new COM('{GUID}');`, and I get the type info with `com_print_typeinfo($com);`, so I can see the object should have the methods `FuncName1()`, `FuncName2()` and `FuncName3()`, but when I try to call any of them with `$com->FuncName1(param1, param2);`, what it returns is this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method com::SomeMethod() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\www\test.php on line 22

Comment: Is it properly registered on the system? I'd see about finding the DLL and register it with `regsvr32 nameof.dll` or if it is out-of-proc EXE run the EXE with `nameof.exe /regserver`

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you. Yes it's an .exe. I did what you suggested. Still the same.

Comment: Forgot to mention My system is on x64, and the .exe file is compiled for x32, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit version of PHP or 32-bit version of PHP?

Comment: phpinfo() : Architecture x86

Comment: So you have a 32-bit program (PHP) instantiating a 32-bit COM server. What happens if you run PHP with admin privileges?

Comment: I ran the script from cmd, always returns the same. I'm not sure if it's related to the *undefined method* error, but when I use com_get_active_object(), to access a running instance of the application, I get *Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Operation unavailable ' ...*, which after some googling, I think it may be related to insufficient user permission. But I cannot be sure it's even that or the other. It's crazy. Anyways, I intend to test on a 32-bit system and come back with the result.

Comment: So, I tested on a windows 7 system on 32-bit, with 32-bit PHP architecture. The results were the same. I also updated the question with more info. thks

Comment: I don't usually do this, but if you could make available your com objects EXE by emailing it to me at mpetch@capp-sysware.com I could take a closer look .

Comment: Emailing the file is inappropriate here, as that file isn't available to future users of this site who find this question. The information to produce the problem needs to be contained here, in the question itself, and so does the information needed for the answer.

Comment: What classes does the typelib for the Delphi COM control export? I see zero information on the Delphi side of things in your question, but you've elected to tag it Delphi.

Comment: @KenWhite, thanks for taking the time on this question. I tagged this question Delphi because this server app is made with Delphi, but I would't now what info is relevant from this side of thing, so I would,t know where to begin. I will try to include as much information as I have access to, when you ask for it. For starters, I will update my question with some code extracted from *_TLB.pas* file.

Comment: @webcrazymaniac have you been able to make a Delphi Test Client that is able to call your Delphi Server without problems?

Comment: @ChristianHolmJørgensen, yes, this application has been used successfully for years, but never with a PHP client.

Comment: I don't really know if it's obvious from the type library source code, but could it be that the *IDispatch*  interface is not actually implemented?

Comment: @webcrazymaniac: No, it isn't. The Delphi wrapper was generated automatically by importing the typelib. Automatable classes must implement IDispatch, and the typelib clearly contained information that said it was automatable. Ergo, IDispatch is implemented. (Also, if you know Delphi at all, all COM automation classes automatically implement IDispatch.)

Comment: @KenWhite, thank you. The thing is I have no experience with Delphi what so ever. No idea how to go about this.

Comment: Another hunch is about Windows user rights, and the fact that PHP is actually a process and not a service, therefore some Windows access limitations may obstruct the script from running correctly.

Comment: @kenwhite : I know where you are coming from and tend to disagree in this case. If the file was made available (even on github) we may be able to determine exactly why the issue exists, and if need be present the information found and have the OP update the question with more relevant information. Right now this is hit and miss because we are relying on the OP to give all the information, although we could still missing something vital. If I had received the file, I would have informed the OP of information that should be added to the Q that they may have missed.

Comment: Does it work when you call a method without any parameters? Maybe the parameters are defined the wrong way. Did you try to use `Variant` tor the parameters? http://php.net/manual/de/class.variant.php

Comment: @Wosi, I did try Variant parameters, and methods that don't take any.

Comment: Just a side note. Where you use `foreach` and it complains about there being no iterator. That is very likely. Unless the COM interface follows the requirements of providing certain functions to allow itself to be used as a Collection - it will fail. And that is assuming PHP allows a COM interface to be used as an iterator (not sure PHP will check that a COM object follows the proper convention to be an iterator, even if the object appears to be a collection)

Comment: Are you supposed to traverse through interfaces, such as `$com->ISrvObject->FuncName1()`?

Comment: @HalfCrazed, no it's not the case

Comment: It might be worth checking the types of the parameters on your method calls.  The error might be based on not finding a matching signature including overloads.  I know the com extension automatically handles types and references for us, but it seems possible that there might be a typing issue.  http://php.net/manual/en/class.variant.php  good luck.

Comment: Is the the actual error message? Because if so then you're calling SomeMethod in your test.php script and SomeMethod isn't a valid method for that class.

Answer (score 1):

Many things can go wrong with COM but I will try to help as best I can.
I know that you use terms to describe the issue, like calling $com->SomeMethod(), but you need to be more specific in this case.

COM exposes its classes and functionality through two basic interfaces IUnknown and IDispatch.
It also has a DLL structure of C type, to expose functions (Not methods or classes) to the "out side" world.
Languages that can link directly to a DLL's, by reading the export table (like Delphi), make their calls directly on the interface exposed by the COM (Using IUnknown interface).

Script languages (like javascript, PHP python etc.) cannot call directly on the interface. Instead they use IDispatch interface.
This interface serve as a proxy that expose all COM functionality through simple text.
The IDispatch interface define standard methods for:

 1. querying a COM on the interfaces it exposes

 2. The methods' names of an object.

 3. The parameters for each method.

In your post you display that IDispatch exposed three methods:

 1. FuncName1

 2. FuncName2

 3. FuncName3

Therefore you cannot call SomeMethod on ISrvObject because it is not exposed via the IDispatch interface.
**NOTE:** COM uses WideString (UTF-16) text when exposing its interface. Take that into account once you do make a call on the interface methods.

Comment: SomeMethod as any of the given three I ment.